# How to bind several textboxes to specific items in a Dictionary in a custom item (C#, winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a custom class that has a Dictionary in it. I create and instance of that class and create blank entries for the dictionary.

I want to bind a number of textboxes to entries in that dictionary in C#, windforms. I have seen similar questions, but none quite address this issue that I have found.

For example,

```
public class GasketDetails
{
    public Dictionary<int, double> QminDict { get; set; }
    public GasketDetails()
    {
        QminDict = new Dictionary<int, double>();
        QminDict.Add(20,0);
        QminDict.Add(100,0);
    }
}



private void initTextBoxBinding()
    {
        ChosenGasket = new GasketDetails();
        tb20Qmin.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ???, ???));
        tb100Qmin.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ???, ???));
    }
```

Comment: Do you want two-way binding?

Comment: No, that's not so important. I only need the dictionary updated from the textbox. I won't be changing the dictionary and then wanting the textbox to update. However, I will change the textbox programatically sometimes and want that to also update the dictionary, not just when the user enters data.

Comment: Don't use binding for that.  Data-binding is great in the right context.  This is not the right context.  Just write code to move the data back and forth.  If you're determined to bind then either redefine that `GasketDetails` class so it is binding-friendly or else create another class that is and can pass the data through.  If you take that second option though, you'll still be writing extra code so, unless you want to reuse it, it's not really worth it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney is right. If you want using databinding, you need to create `ViewModel` class which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Then in the viewmodel you can create own property for every item of Dictionary and bind them to the textboxes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Data Binding TextBox to a Dictionary Item in C# Windows Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668472/how-to-data-binding-textbox-to-a-dictionary-item-in-c-sharp-windows-form)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'l try and change the way it's done. It just seemed like it would be less code to do it with databinding, but maybe not in this case.