# ComboBox DisplayMember object attribute that is within a KVP dictonary

Tags: c#, forms, dictionary, combobox

What I have is a dict that looks like this.

`Dictionary<int, BooksInv> books = new Dictionary<int, BooksInv>();`

BooksInv is an class with attributes Title and Author. I am trying to have the combobox display the Title attribute. Problem is I am unable to drill down enough to get the Title as the displaymember.

Using the below method only works if dealing with a list of the objects not a KVP as I am trying.

`cmbBx1.DisplayMember = "Value";`
 `cmbBx1.DataSource = new BindingSource(books , null);`

I have been looking for the solution to this for a while and have not solved this problem. Is this even a possible feat or is adding extra code, creating a separate list just to use in the combobox the only way to go?

Comment: Is it “required” to use a `Dictionary<int, BookInv>` for this? The `ComboBox` works well with an `IList` of some kind. A `BindingList<BooksInv>` may simplify things. I would even consider writing a method that takes your dictionary and returns a `BindingList<BookInv>` just for the combo box if you “must” use the `Dictionary`.

Comment: Try using an explicit binding like described here (closest thing i found): https://stackoverflow.com/a/12668865/14865005

Comment: What about `cmbBx1.DataSource = new BindingSource(books.Values , null);`?